# What are the ways of maintaining state of an object throughout the react js pages

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state-management

so in our project the data will be entered on the 1st page component and we want that data on the 5th page not on the 2nd 3rd 4th page.
we are not able to maintain the state of object till the 5th page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Context](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) item.

You can create an object which can be accesible in multiple components. This can, of course, be combined with state.

1-Create the context (in this case I made a component wrapper to make it easier to include in the code.

```
export const DataContext= React.createContext({
  data: 60, //Default values in case no value is provided
  setData: () => {}
});

export function DataContextContainer({children}) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(60);

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{ data, setData}}>
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

2-Wrap your desired components (which will read that data) with the component

```
import {DataContextContainer} from "./DataContextContainer";
 ...
<DataContextContainer>
    ...
         <YourComponent/>
    ...
</DataContextContainer>
```

3- Now you can easily have access to that object in any of the components wrapped using the hook [useContext](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) or [a context consumer](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer).

```
import {DataContext} from './DataContext'

...
    const {data, setData} = useContext(DataContext);
...
```

4- Use it in your input:

```
<input type="text" value={data} onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)}/>
```

Comment: what will be the syntax for taking values in input text box

Comment: I dont exactly understand what you mean but I suppose you can do onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)}

Comment: I have created a UseContext component and made a variable inside it. Now i want to take input from input text box and set the value in that UseContext variable . Im not able to understand it

Comment: I updated the answer I gave to add what you should do in your input